# Dynamic Parallel stages in Jenkins Pipeline outside 'script' block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to construct parallel stages dynamically, as demonstrated [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/3090) and [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922168-Pipeline-Parallel-execution-of-tasks). Specifically, I am trying to do this in a function defined outside the scope of the pipeline, e.g.:

```
pipeline{
  stages{
    stage('CI'){
      steps{
        doDynamicParallelSteps()
      }
    }
  }
}

def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
  tests = [:]
  for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
    tests["${f}"] = {
      node {
        stage("${f}") {
          echo '${f}'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  parallel tests
}
```

The problem is, it seems this only works when the dynamic parallel generation code is inside a script{} block within the steps{} block of the pipeline (as seen in the first source).

When running something similar to the code snippet above, I see this error in jenkins:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [teststage, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@2e1b48b4]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), trim(), size(), next(), size()
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.parallelHandler(WorkflowScript:1383)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there any way to have it defined as a function in the way I showed in the initial code snippet, or am I stuck with having a ton of script{} blocks in my pipeline definition?

Comment: What is in line 1383 of your script? The error seems to be caused there according to the error message

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The **declarative pipeline** does not allow you to put Groovy code inside `steps {}` block - it expects a valid Jenkins pipeline step in this place. This is why `script {}` block got introduced that can be put inside the `steps {}` block to execute some Groovy code.

If you need flexibility and non-opinionated syntax then you might use **scripted pipeline** instead. Here you can mix Groovy code with existing pipeline steps with almost no limitations.

[Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare) explains shortly the difference between both approaches and why they exist:

> When Jenkins Pipeline was first created, Groovy was selected as the foundation. Jenkins has long shipped with an embedded Groovy engine to provide advanced scripting capabilities for admins and users alike. Additionally, the implementors of Jenkins Pipeline found Groovy to be a solid foundation upon which to build what is now referred to as the "Scripted Pipeline" DSL. [2].
>
> As it is a fully featured programming environment, Scripted Pipeline offers a tremendous amount of flexibility and extensibility to Jenkins users. The Groovy learning-curve isn’t typically desirable for all members of a given team, so Declarative Pipeline was created to offer a simpler and more opinionated syntax for authoring Jenkins Pipeline.
>
> Both are fundamentally the same Pipeline sub-system underneath. They are both durable implementations of "Pipeline as code." They are both able to use steps built into Pipeline or provided by plugins. Both are able to utilize Shared Libraries

Your example in scripted pipeline may look like this:

```
node {
  stage('CI') {
    doDynamicParallelSteps()
  }
}

def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
  tests = [:]
  for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
    tests["${f}"] = {
      node {
        stage("${f}") {
          echo '${f}'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  parallel tests
}
```

And declarative pipeline with `script {}` block in steps would look like this:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('CI'){
      steps{
        script {
            doDynamicParallelSteps()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
  tests = [:]
  for (f in findFiles(glob: '**/html/*.html')) {
    tests["${f}"] = {
      node {
        stage("${f}") {
          echo '${f}'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  parallel tests
}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I've copied an even simpler version of that block into my pipeline file, and it still does not work and throws the same error as above when it gets to the point of executing the `parallel tests` line. For some reason the line it's pointing to in the stacktrace is actually the stage declaration in the dynamic parallel steps function. The strangest part is that I created a separate sample pipeline in the same jenkins instance, and THAT worked. So I guess it's something to do with my specific pipeline file, but I have no idea how to even begin debugging.

Comment: So, a coworker of mine figured out the error, and it's really dumb... One of the arguments of the original function definition (not the same as the code snippet) was called "stage", and it was of type String. This was there so I could pass in context of what stage in the pipeline was calling the function. The problem was, this "stage" variable was overwriting the the stage() declaration in the `node{ stage("..."){ ... } }` block. This is also why we saw the error in the stack trace, with jenkins complaining that String has no method call().

Quite the humbling experience.

Comment: @szymon-stepniak It shall be noted that the stage in the dynamic step won't run in the correct git reference (assuming git): the declarative pipeline handles the reference update in normal steps but won't do anything in this dynamic stage. This is not an obvious mistake so it might be worth a disclaimer :)

Comment: in my case I also needed to add ```def var = "${f}"``` between the ```for``` loop to the ```tests``` dictionary and use ```var``` inside the  stage, otherwise I always got the last element in ```findFiles``` for all threads (In my case I used array list)

Comment: I GOT below exception intermittently 
**** was marked offline: Connection was broken: java.io.EOFException
..... hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:36)
 at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
 at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)

Comment: @dsaydon - that tip saved me after tons of confusion. Do you happen to have an explanation for why you need to assign it to a different variable for it to work appropriately in the stage block?

Comment: @TylerNielsen - because you need to `define` a new `variable` to each thread in the `parallel` , otherwise it will use the same `variable` for all of the threads which will results by overwriting the `variable` again and again until the last thread

Comment: @dsaydon - huh, to me this looks akin to a closure, so I would have thought that value of ${f} would be passed/stored into each parallel block as it's getting called iterating in for loop. Thanks

Comment: omg - same error as @ClaytonKeleher 4 years later. :/