# How to reusing duplicate code for Jenkins Parallel includes the Stages section?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

1.The following code can be replicated locally

how do i reuse the redundant code above, The code here may be a bit special. The code that needs to be reused includes stages. This is because an upstream build issues testing tasks to a downstream job(the code here), which is partially serialized in a producer-consumer model to control the degree of parallelism

```
def fill_list() {
    def test_list = [] // or [].asSynchronized()
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        test_list.add(i.toString())
    }
    return test_list
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Assign Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    test_list = fill_list()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('CTest Stage') {
            parallel {
                stage('stream_1') {
                    agent any
                    stages {
                        stage('installation') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    while (test_list.size() > 0) {
                                        def current_task = 0
                                        try {
                                            current_task = test_list.pop()
                                            } catch (err) {
                                            println('current stream ends')
                                            break
                                        }
                                        stage("stream_1_${current_task}") {
                                            script {
                                                sleep(0.5)
                                                println("ctest -R ${current_task} -N") // do test
                                                println("node executor num: ${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage('clean') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    println('stream_1_workspace clean')
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('stream_2') {
                    agent any
                    stages {
                        stage('installation') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    while (test_list.size() > 0) {
                                        def current_task = 0
                                        try {
                                            current_task = test_list.pop()
                                        } catch (err) {
                                            println('current stream ends')
                                            break
                                        }
                                        stage("stream_2_${current_task}") {
                                            script {
                                                sleep(0.5)
                                                println("ctest -R ${current_task} -N") // do test
                                                println("node executor num: ${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage('clean') {
                            steps {
                                script {
                                    println('stream_1_workspace clean')
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure I got your question.
 do you want to reuse all the above in a different pipeline?- If yes , Have you tried the Jenkins Shared Library approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that would provide a map containing reusable code and execute it in parallel. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237378/10721630

```
def parallelExecution() {
  streams = [:]
  for (int count = 1; count <= 2; count++) {
    def temp = count
    streams["stream_${temp}"] = {
      node {
        stage('installation') {
          while (test_list.size() > 0) {
            def current_task = 0
            try {
              current_task = test_list.pop()
            } catch (err) {
              println('current stream ends')
              break
            }
            stage("stream_${temp}_${current_task}") {
              println("ctest -R ${current_task} -N") // do test
              println("node executor num: ${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}")
            }
          }
        }
        stage('clean') {
          println("stream_${temp}_workspace clean")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  parallel streams
}
```

In the pipeline script call the new function.

```
...
  stage('CTest Stage') {
    steps {
      script {
        parallelExecution()
      }
    }
  }
...
```