# Declarative dynamic parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I figure I’m doing something unorthodox here, but I’d like to stick to declarative for convenience **while** dynamically generating parallel steps.

I found a way to do something like that, but [mixing both paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237378/515594), which doesn’t seem to work well with the BlueOcean UI (multiple stages inside each parallel branch do not show up properly).

The closest I got was with something like this:

```
def accounts() {
  return ["dynamic", "list"]
}

def parallelJobs() {
  jobs = []

  for (account in accounts()) {
    jobs[] = stage(account) {
      steps {
        echo "Step for $account"
      }
    }
  }

  return jobs
}

# this is inside a shared library, called by my Jenkinsfile, like what is described
# under "Defining Declarative Pipelines in Shared Libraries" in
# https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/
def call() {
  pipeline {
    stages {
      stage('Build all variations') {
        parallel parallelJobs()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is Jenkins errors like this:

```
Expected a block for parallel @ line X, column Y.
           parallel parallelJobs()
           ^
```

So, I was wondering if there is a way I could transform that list of stages, returned by `parallelJobs()`, into the block expected by Jenkins...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to return a `map` of stages. Following is a working pipeline example.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Parallel') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelJobs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def accounts() {
  return ["dynamic", "list"]
}

def parallelJobs() {
  jobs = [:]

  for (account in accounts()) {
    jobs[account] = { stage(account) {
       echo "Step for $account"
     }
    }
  }
  return jobs
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is the mixed approach I already used, calling the `parallel` from inside a `script` block. As I tried to explain in the question, I'm trying to stick to declarative.

Comment: You can't call groovy functions within a declarative pipeline. The only reason you are able to call `parallel parallelJobs()` in your example is because you are already in a `call()` block, so that ship has already sailed. So if your question is. can you make dynamic stages with just declarative syntax, the answer is no.

Comment: Well, my question is actually the last sentence: would be possible to cast/transform that list of stages to the block expected by Jenkins, even if I have to do heavy transformations using Jenkins internals? From what I see in the [model definition](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/model/Parallel.groovy#L43), it should be possible (unless I'm looking in the wrong places)